# Tests wont run with Karma, Browserify, Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-runner, browserify

Losing what little hair I have left with this...

My tests never get run. Browserify seems to bundle everything up ok but then nothing happens.

karma.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: './',

        frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],

        files: [

            "./app/main.js",

            {pattern: './app/**/*.js', included: false},
            {pattern: './app/**/*.spec.js', included: false},
            {pattern: './node_modules/angular/angular.js', included: false},
            {pattern: './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js', included: false},
        ],



        exclude: [
        ],

        browserify: {

            debug: true
        },

        preprocessors: {
            "./app/**/*.js": ["browserify"]
        },

        reporters: ['progress'],

        port: 9876,

        colors: true,

        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

        autoWatch: false,

        browsers: [
            "Chrome"
        ],

        singleRun: true,

        concurrency: Infinity
    })
}
```

main.js:

```
require('angular');

var app = angular.module('app', []);

require ("./+filters");
require ("./+services");
require ("./+directives");
require ("./+controllers");
```

time.spec.js:

```
"use strict";

var angular = require("angular");
var mocks = require("angular-mocks");

describe("The Time Service", () => {


    var timeService;

beforeEach (module("app"));

beforeEach (
        inject(["TimeService", (_timeService_) => {

            timeService = _timeService_;

}])
);


it("should be 12:00", () => {
    expect(timeService.get()).toBe("12:00");
});

});
```

The folder structure looks like:

```
+
|   .babelrc
|   .gitignore
|   app.js
|   favicon.ico
|   gulpfile.js
|   karma.conf.js
|   package.json
|   readme.md
|   test.config.js
|   tree.txt
|
+---app
|   |   main.js
|   |
|   +---+controllers
|   |   |   index.js
|   |   |
|   |   \---main
|   |           main.e2e.js
|   |           main.js
|   |           main.spec.js
|   |
|   +---+directives
|   |   |   index.js
|   |   |
|   |   \---about
|   |           about.js
|   |           about.scss
|   |
|   +---+filters
|   |   |   index.js
|   |   |
|   |   \---reverse
|   |           reverse.js
|   |           reverse.specx.js
|   |
|   \---+services
|       |   index.js
|       |
|       \---time
|               time.js
|               time.spec.js
|
```

Any pointers gratefully accepted.

TIA,
Jeff

Comment: have you tried debugging your tests in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to browserify the bundle first and then the spec files:

```
preprocessors: {
  'app/main.js': [ 'browserify' ],
  'app/**/*.spec.js': [ 'browserify' ]
},
```

This is how I have it set up, and it seems to be working for me.